# permanence or maintenance

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following two sentences is the most idiomatic?

> This justifies the **permanence** of the candidate in the current institution
>
> This justifies the **maintenance** of the candidate in the current institution

Is there any suitable alternative?

Comment: How about *continuance* or simply, *This justifies keeping the candidate in the current institution.*

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the suggestion. I actually like continuance.

Comment: “Retention” could work too, depending on the situation.

Comment: I'd say that you should be using the present progressive/continuous tense here instead. You can use a verb rather than a noun to be more direct/concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, but this is best expressed with a verb. And I'm not sure that your sentence expresses what you intend it to, but I can't say for certain based on the lack of context. I think you either mean to say **maintaining/retaining *them* in *their* current *position*** or **maintaining/retaining *them* in *our institution***.

That I'm able to suggest so many possible constructions should demonstrate to you that your sentence is ambiguous and should therefore be rephrased.

You're describing taking an action that begins in the present and that will project into the future. Because of this, it's more direct to use a verb in the present progressive tense. It's too verbose and indirect when you use a noun.

You could, however, say either:

> This justifies **[us] maintaining** the candidate in the current
>   institution.

-or-

> This justifies **[us] retaining** the candidate in the current institution.

If you're not going to use a verb, then you probably should include the *possessive adjective **our*** in front of *the maintenance* because it's actually the direct object.

In that case, you'd say:

> This justifies **our** maintenance of the candidate in the current
>   institution.

-or-

> This justifies **our** retention of the candidate in the current
>   institution.

Another option would be to use either the present or past perfect form of *justify*, depending on the context. Use the present perfect unless you're trying to indicate that this preceded another action in time, like, say, this person's termination of employment/firing.

> This **has/had justified** the maintenance of the candidate in the
>   current institution

-or

> This **has/had justified** the retention of the candidate in the
>   current institution.

Depending on what you're trying to express, it *might* be applicable to use the present/past **perfect progressive tense**, as in:

> This **has/had been justifying** the maintenance of the candidate in this position, ***but/until/before/etc***.

Again, it's present unless it precedes another event.